Voltage Transformer Troubleshooting
I have an LVAC Switchboard with 3x Incomers, all fitted with a 250A 4P MCCB. On the incoming side of each incomer, I wire to a 25VA wye-wye voltage transformer 400/110VAC. The secondary side of the transformer feeds a meter & a phase failure relay. The issue i am having is that when I pull one phase, the phase failure relay does not automatically changeover to supply 2 & the voltage on the incoming side only drops by around 10-15V, not enough to trigger a changeover to supply 2. The changeover only happens automatically when I lose 2x phases. Any idea as to why this is? The phase failure relay has a nominal voltage of 110VAC. Seems to be it is holding onto voltage somehow. How would I rectify this to make it changeover when I lose one phase?

Relays tend to be specified with a pull-in voltage, and a drop-out voltage, above and below which they're guaranteed to do the thing you expect. What are those voltages for your relay? They can be rather different to what you'd hope.

If meter or phase failure relays are internally conected in Delta, with only 2 phases voltages, the missing phase will be generated and transformed to primary. That could explain why the incoming side drops some voltage but still is present. Do a test with some load (maybe 3 x bulbs ) to confirm this hypotethical case.

Part numbers and measured voltages might help. I am surprised you need a transformer at all; 400V energy meters and phase failure relays are commonplace.
